# Don't show Xcode navigator on run

Tags: xcode

I have a dual-head setup for Xcode that I use for developing on iOS, with a split-pane editor and counterpart assistant on each screen. When I run a project it throws that away and takes over half my (active) screen with the debug navigator and console -- is there a way to have Xcode *not* show those on run? Or, even better, always show them on a particular screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferences->Behaviors. The default behaviour for "Running: Generates Output" is to switch to the debugger view and show the console - either turn that off or configure it to do something else.

Comment: Ah, excellent. There doesn't seem to be a way to peg it to the primary or secondary display, but just disabling the thing is enough for me. Thanks!